# I need sftp vhost permissions on lightsail plesk ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, plesk

desperately attempting to upload/open the /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/ on using PLESK on ubuntu thru aws lightsail.

I am able to connect to the folder structure via sftp using the ubuntu credentials/keypair and can navigate to the root of vhosts, however, I cannot access the domain folder.

I have altered my ftpuser root permissions to match the ubuntu permissions>> result: removes access to sftp entirely AND I have altered the root ubuntu permissions to give it FTP/Plesk permissions>> result: removes access to server completely and I have to reload the whole instance.

I have scoured the web/plesk and aws for support, but nothing.

TLDR: all I want to do is upload to the actual domain folder using ftp over plesk on lightsail.. HELP

EDIT for clarification:

When attempting to connect to the domain folder over FTP using login: ubuntu & my key file, this happens

```
Status:      Directory listing of "/var/www/vhosts" successful
Status:      Retrieving directory listing of "/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com"...
Command:     cd "xxxxxx.com"
Error:       Directory /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com: permission denied
Error:       Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

when attempting to connect with my Plesk FTP credentials to the server, this happens

```
Command:    open "ftpuser@xxxxx.com" 22
Status:     Unable to use key file "C:\LightsailDefaultKey-us-east-1.pem" (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key (old PEM format)) 
Status:     Using username "ftpuser". 
Error:      FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

aws credentials.. ok to connect to ftp and navigate around, but cannot connect to plesk managed folders

plesk ftp user credentials... cannot connect to server via ftp

```
when i give permissions to AWS Credentials.. it still FAILS
when i give AWS Credentials permissions to PLESK .. it still FAILS
```

does anybody know how to do this?
does this help clarify?

Comment: "however, I cannot access the domain folder." What happens when you try? Please [edit] your question to show the actual permissions for the directories that you're trying to access, and what happens when you try to access it through SFTP. Include any error messages that you get.

Comment: thx kenster.. I attempted to clarify... I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the user who owns the domain in the plesk panel for connecting through FTP (e.g. Filezilla). You can edit the user using "Web Hosting Access" under the settings (add ssh permission as well).

[image: Plesk panel Screenshot]

Also if you want to SSH using putty :  Connect with the user 'ubuntu' and the key. After you are connected, 'sudo su ToYourPleskUser'.

(I'm not sure whether this is the right way, but it works for me; please enlighten me if anybody else know how to do it right)

Edit: Points to note:
Amazon Lightsail: Go to your instance settings, make sure port 21 is open in Networking tab.

Filezilla settings: Protocol: FTP, Host: Your public IP, Port: 21, Encryption: Only use plain FTP, Logon type: Normal, User: The one you created using Plesk control panel, In transfer settings tab: Transfer mode set to 'Active'

PS: I came across the same situation again and googling took me to this answer, but as the Filezilla part was not complete, it took some time for me to figure it out. Lesson learned: Put down the complete process when answering.